# VK API получение статистики по кампании

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу получить статистику для рекламной кампании.
Метод [вот.](https://vk.com/dev/ads.getStatistics)
Проблема в том, что даже при тесте на странице документации структура stats почему-то пустая.

```
{

    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1001065958,
            "type": "campaign",
            "stats": [ ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Возможно проблема в том что в кампанию не было внесено средств ? Хотя даже в таком случае статистику 0 должен возвращать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный метод возвращает пустой массив `stats`, если за указанный период ваша рекламная кампания простаивала. Вы не вносили средства, соответственно, ваша кампания не "крутилась", поэтому статистики по ней нет.

Почему возвращается пустой массив, а не `0` или что-нибудь еще? Потому что этот массив содержит в себе множество объектов, сгруппированных по параметру `period`, поэтому было бы немного странно вместо ожидаемого массива отдавать число или булево выражение. Дней нет - нет и объектов со статистикой по ним.

На моем скриншоте можете проверить работоспособность метода на существующей кампании с группировкой по дням:

[image: Пример работы метода ads.getStatistics]